# Azure Pipelines: 2 build are triggered for PR

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps yaml pipelines. Whenever I push to a branch that has an open pull request, 2 builds are triggered: One with the name of the PR, the other with the name of the commit, see

[image]

The trigger section in both, source and target branch, is equal:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - "*"
# builds is already triggered once by branch
pr: none
```

**How can I avoid triggering 2 builds for the same commit using the same (branched) pipeline.yaml in both branches?**

Comment: Is YAML file located on both branches? As I can see resourceServer branch and 1928 get triggered. If the yaml file is located on both branches then it is normal that both get triggered. In order to resolve this you could rename the .yml file on one branch or follow a different approach regarding branches and triggers

Comment: yes, the yaml file is located in both branches. `ResouceServer` is a branch from `main`. Renaming the yaml is not an option - it's an PR. What do you mean with a different apporach regarding triggers?

Comment: You have the .yml file on both branches, this is why it gets triggered two times. The .yml is located on both branch and you do not have a filter regarding which branch to build. You could add a filter for the branch on each branch and only when you commit on the specific branch the pipeline will run. For example for ResouceServer include only ResouceServer branch and on 1928 include only this branch and exclude others.

Comment: editing the pipeline yaml in the branch would contradict normal dev/git workflow. I'd like to prevent a 2nd build run for the PR to main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to CI trigger on your branch and PR build validation policy running the pipeline automatically.

To avoid that either

1. In the build validation policy - disable automatic queuing.
2. Or mark the PR as draft, while changes are being worked on.

After this change any of the changes will only trigger CI build/pipeline, and when ready just publish the PR or queue the PR manually